# E: unable to locate package pip

Tags: android, python, ubuntu, pip

I have been trying to set up Python-android environment, and kept getting this error message:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential patch git-core ccache ant pip python-devsudo: /var/lib/sudo/plaix writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
[sudo] password for plaix: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pip
```

Comment: I don't know whether it really belongs here (you may be better off asking this at http://askubuntu.com). But aside from that, I don't know where you got this from but maybe you mean the package `python-pip`?

Comment: While some `sudo` commands seem to succeed, there's a error about permissions on sudo's files. Maybe that got pasted accidentally. But if you're getting errors when you use `sudo`, you may want to post a question on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) to get help with it. Or [this related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/240252/sudo-var-lib-sudo-navneet-writable-by-non-owner-040777-should-be-mode-0700) may help (please note that your problem is *not necessarily* as severe as the problem faced by the OP there). That's peripheral to your main problem here (which is a wrong package name).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Ubuntu, [`pip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pip.1.html) is provided by the [`python-pip`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-pip&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) package. You can install it in the Software Center, or, if you prefer to use the command line:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

If you have not already installed [`python-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python-dev&searchon=names) and [`build-essential`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=build-essential&searchon=names), you should install them too. (But it seems your `apt-get` command *might* have successfully installed them. If you're not sure, you can check by trying to install them again. Or with `apt-cache policy python-dev build-essential`.)

Once the necessary software is installed, if you wish to update it further, you can do so with `pip` itself, by running:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip 
sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

***Source:*** [How to install pip on Ubuntu](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/02/how-install-pip-ubuntu/) by [Eliot](http://www.saltycrane.com/about/) (dated, but should still apply).

Answer (score 11):

To install pip, download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).
Then run this command:

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

It will download and install pip from the source.
To check if pip is installed, type this:

```
which pip
```

it will show where pip is located

```
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

or just type:

```
pip
```

Answer (score 3):

The package you want is not called `pip`, the name depends on the python version.

Python 2:
`sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Python 3:
`sudo apt install python3-pip`

Comment: This worked for me, why downvoted not sure, upvoting it as for python3 this is a right answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using python 3.xx version, try this.

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Answer (score 0):

Python packages generally have a `python` prefix.

Try installing `python-pip` instead of `pip` (this may change depending the distribution you are working on).

Answer (score 0):

Just update using:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove python-pip-whl

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip-whl
```

now try again it will work