# Getting ImportError: No module named 'Crypto' after installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, importerror, pycrypto

I am getting `ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'` error when trying to run. I have installed pycrypto using `pip install pycrypto` and updated it also. Everything I have tried to far has been unsuccessful.

Tried:

- reinstalling pycrypto,
- updating both python and pycrypto

Any suggestions?

Comment: give a try with sudo apt-get install also

Comment: I get this same error - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716569/e-unable-to-locate-package-pip

Comment: Try pip3 install pycrypto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages says, it does not able to find the module so please try to run below command,

```
#pip list -- # what does it show to you, if it would have installed successfully it will show you up there.
```

if "pip install pycrypto" doesn't work so try to download the source tar ball and try to install it from prompt.

```
pip download pycrypto
```

it will download tar.gz file.. so you can install using with `pip install --no-index --find-links /path/to/some/dir/ pycrypto`

for python3.5 version

```
python3.5 -m pip install pycrypto
```

this will install in python3.5 environment and after that you can able to import pycrypto module

Comment: so this tells me its already done and in the python2.7 dir, so if im using python3.5 which does not have pycrypto in its dir, I guess id need it there but im not sure how.

Comment: I have modified the previous comment.. you can still try to install using below command
python3.5 -m pip install <package>

Answer (score 0):

Is python defined properly on your machine?
Make sure PATH environment variable has python's installation folder in it

Comment: looked this up and entered 'export ATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python"' in terminal, still does not work, have I done this correctly?

Comment: Did you mean 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python'? (your command is missing the P in PATH)

Comment: ah thank you, form had a typo now I have python when I 'echo $PATH' but still get error.